# Extract output tensor from any layer of onnx model

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, conv-neural-network, onnx

I want to extract the output of different layers of an onnx model (e.g., squeezenet.onnx, etc.) during image inference. I am trying to use the code in [How to extract output tensor from any layer of models][1]:

```
    # add all intermediate outputs to onnx net
    ort_session = ort.InferenceSession('<you path>/model.onnx')
    org_outputs = [x.name for x in ort_session.get_outputs()]
    
    model = onnx.load('<you path>/model.onnx')
    for node in model.graph.node:
        for output in node.output:
            if output not in org_outputs:
                model.graph.output.extend([onnx.ValueInfoProto(name=output)])
    
    # excute onnx
    ort_session = ort.InferenceSession(model.SerializeToString())
    outputs = [x.name for x in ort_session.get_outputs()]
    img_path = '<you path>/input_img.raw'
    img = get_image(img_path, show=True)
    transform_fn = transforms.Compose([
       transforms.Resize(224),
       transforms.ToTensor(),
    ])
    img = transform_fn(img)
    img = img.expand_dims(axis=0)
    ort_outs = ort_session.run(outputs, {'data': img} )
    ort_outs = OrderedDict(zip(outputs, ort_outs))
```

I am getting the error below although I managed to have the input size required:

```
---> 40 ort_outs = ort_session.run(outputs, {'data': img} )
     41 ort_outs = OrderedDict(zip(outputs, ort_outs))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/onnxruntime/capi/onnxruntime_inference_collection.py in run(self, output_names, input_feed, run_options)
    198             output_names = [output.name for output in self._outputs_meta]
    199         try:
--> 200             return self._sess.run(output_names, input_feed, run_options)
    201         except C.EPFail as err:
    202             if self._enable_fallback:

RuntimeError: Input must be a list of dictionaries or a single numpy array for input 'data'.
```

How can I fix this? Appreciate your help! Thank you
[1]: https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/issues/1455

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that is not possible. However you could re-export the original  model from PyTorch to onnx, and add the output of the desired layer to the return statement of the forward method of your model. (you might have to feed it through a couple of methods up to the first forward method in your model)